# Cannot get array property by using Parse JSON groovy

Tags: json, groovy

I'm new to Groovy. But, I can try with some simple code lines to extract the data.

I have read the from [Parse JSON using groovy script (using JsonSlurper)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42603087/parse-json-using-groovy-script-using-jsonslurper). But it didn't help in my case.

My code line:

```
{
  "errors": false,
  "address_data": [
    {
      "address_id": "567",
      "township": {
        "id": "41079",
        "name": "Test Data"
      },
      "city": {
        "id": "1622",
        "name": "Test City"
      },
      "region": {
        "id": "663",
        "name": "Metro Test"
      },
      "stock_source_code": "Test",
      "is_default_address": false
    },
    {
      "address_id": "45444",
      "township": {
        "id": "41079",
        "name": "Test Test"
      },
      "city": {
        "id": "1622",
        "name": "Test City"
      },
      "region": {
        "id": "663",
        "name": "Metro Test Taguig"
      },
      "is_default_address": true
    },
    {
      "address_id": "45444",
      "township": {
        "id": "888888",
        "name": "Apas"
      },
      "city": {
        "id": "432",
        "name": "Test City"
      },
      "region": {
        "id": "591",
        "name": "Test Cebu"
      },
      "stock_source_code": "testce",
      "is_default_address": false
    }
  ]
}
```

My code lines:

```
def response = "data_above";
def object = new JsonSlurper().parseText(response);
def errors = object.errors
if (errors == false) { //could access object.errors property
    log.info "Checking condition"
    def addressData = object.address_data // Cannot get the data
}
```

How can I get the `address_data` property?

Comment: Try `if (errors)` - `error` is unboxed and `==` is unlikely to be the correct operation

Comment: thanks @ernest_k, it also works with `==` operation. My log message worked.

Comment: My bad. I forgot groovy `==` uses `.equals`...

Comment: What do you mean by *Cannot get the data*? Is `addressData` being set to `null` or are you getting an error?

Comment: I used `println (object.address_data)`. But I didn't see any info.

Comment: Can't reproduce. It prints the object in my test. You may need to post the full code that we can reproduce it with.

Comment: Did you use `println` to print the object?

Comment: Yes. `println(object.address_data)` or `println(addressData)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200383/discussion-between-khoa-truongdinh-and-ernest-k).